# mod_auth_form apache error when restart apache2

Tags: apache, mod-auth-form

I am trying to protect a folder in my directory under name admin and login from html form page.
At my apache server I have edited the default-ssl.conf with following:

```
  <Directory "/var/www/admin">
    AuthFormProvider file
    ErrorDocument 401 "/login.shtml"
    AuthUserFile "/var/www/.htpasswd"
    AuthType form
    AuthName realm
    AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "https://myserver.com/login.html"
    Session On
    SessionCookieName session path=/
  </Directory>
```

My passwords file is .htpasswd and my loginpage is http://myserver.com/login.html.

When I restart my apache I have following error:

AH00526: Syntax error on line 16 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:
Invalid command 'AuthFormProvider', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'start' failed.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

The modules you'll need for this are:

```
a2enmod session
a2enmod session_cookie
a2enmod session_crypto
a2enmod auth_form
a2enmod request
```